# Month number retention cohort calculation issue with Redshift

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I'm trying to calculate user retention cohorts in redshift by month for the last 9 months. But I'm running into an issue where the month cohorts in the below query aren't being rolled into the correct month.

The data types I'm querying are:

userid - varchar
activated-varchar

Here is the query I'm trying to run:

```
with by_month as 
(SELECT
userid
DATE_TRUNC('month', cast ("activated" as date)) AS joined_month
FROM customers
GROUP BY 1, 2),

first_month as
(select userid, 
 joined_month,
 FIRST_VALUE(order_month) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY 
 joined_month asc rows unbounded preceding) AS first
 FROM by_month),

 months as (select userid,
 joined_month,
 first,
 extract(month from (joined_month - first_month)) as month_number
 from first_month)


SELECT
 first as "cohort",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 0",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 1",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 2",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 3",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 4",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 5",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 6",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 7",
  SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 8",
   SUM(CASE WHEN month_number = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " Month 9"
  from months
  where first_month >= '2018-08-01'
 GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

When I get the results back, I get an impossible number for a couple of cohorts:

Such as:

```
Cohort       Month 0  Month 1
'2019-01-01'   95     120
```

I did some digging and found the month numbers aren't being counted correctly For instance, for the cohort of '2019-01-01 the month_ number is t's capturing 0,1, and 3 correctly but 2 is being miss-attributed to month 1. Any help on the fix would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with window function? I don't see any window function in your query.

Comment: You are going to have to supply table column data types; it matters.

Comment: your `by_month` subquery does not contain `order_month` column that is used in the next subquery that reuses `by_month`, the query doesn't seem valid

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone I edited my question to be more relevant.

Comment: After >> SELECT first as "cohort",  <<, then add  first_month,    just to see what value is in it.  It may contain other than what you think.

Comment: @donPablo

`2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z`
 `2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z`
 `2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`
 `2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`
 `2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z`
  `2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z`
   `2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z`
    `2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z`
    `2018-08-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Now,  try >>SELECT userid, joined_month, first_month, month_number FROM months WHERE first = '2019-01-01'  (feel free to add other columns to drill down to the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Now, try

```
SELECT userid, joined_month, first_month, month_number FROM months 
WHERE first = '2019-01-01'
```

(feel free to add other columns to drill down to the problem)  add activated, order_month, etc until you get the right handle on what is causing it.

Comment: thank you! it looks like the issue is with the month_number. It's capturing 0,1, and 3 correctly but 2 is being miss-attributed to month 1. I'm not quite sure how to correct that

Comment: Which SELECT is that mis-attribution happening on?  by_month,  first_month, or months ? Look at >>extract(month from (joined_month - first_month)) as month_number<< Is that supposed to be first_month,  or just  first ??